# What is the fastest way I can determine whether the intersection of multiple sets of integers is nonempty?

Tags: python, math, set

I am part of a undergrad mathematics group. I have a collection of sets of unique integers (sets are varying length). Very often I need  to determine whether the intersection of all sets in the collection is nonempty. I do not need to know what the intersection is, just whether it is nonempty or not. I have to do this a lot. I don't have a lot of experience with time complexity and making efficient algorithms. What is the fastest way to go about this?

I included what I have so far. It's horribly slow. If S has 15+ sets, then the script takes forever.

```
# S is an array of integers
def intersects(S):
    if S == []:
        return True # if S is empty, I deem the intersection nonempty for reasons
    A = S[0]
    for i in range(1, len(S)):
        B = S[i]
        A = get_intersection(A, B) # returns intersection of A and B
        if A == []:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: What's your `get_intersection()` implementation? That might be what's slowing you down here.

Comment: @glhr I convert A into a set, then use A.intersection(B). I was using a self-built method get_intersection(), but I changed it to the python way. However, it did not speed up the process.

Comment: im not aware of any builtin `get_intersection`

Answer (score 1):

set intersection can accept multiple sets

```
S[0].intersection(*S[1:])
```

(or even just `set.intersection(*S)`)

for example

```
>>> s1 = set([1,2,3])
>>> s2 = 2,3,4
>>> s3 = 3,4,5
>>> s1.intersection(s2,s3)
set([3])
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this didn't improve what I originally had.

Comment: what do you mean surely `set.intersection(*S)`  is less code, and almost certainly at least marginally faster than your custom loop

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to put everything into `set.intersection`:

```
import numpy as np

S = [set(np.random.randint(0,100,100)) for _ in range(20)]
set.intersection(*S)
# set()
```